# Laravel 5.4 Displaying editing options in modal from view?

Tags: php, laravel

I have succesfully created an application within Laravel which allows users to edit posts for a item. The current method is by redirecting user to different page where they are able to make changes. However to increase the user expirence I was planning to add 'modal' within the page. Meaning that editing posts will happen within the same page. This method for me partly works. In a aspect that the last or the latest post is only editable post. If I click on any of the posts it makes me only make changes to the latest post. Any help, suggestions or examples are trully appreciated.

Below I have attached my show.blade.php which shows the item infromation and posts.

```
<ul class="list-group">


@foreach ($car->reviews as $review)
<li class="list-group-item">

    <strong>
        Created by: {{ $review->user->name}} {{ $review->created_at->diffForHumans() }}:
        <br>
        Updated by: {{ $review->user->name}} {{ $review->updated_at->diffForHumans() }}:

    </strong>


  <a href="/reviews/{{ $review->id }}/edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" >{{ $review->reviewbody }}</a>


  <a style="float:right;" href="/reviews/{{$review->id}}/delete">Delete</a>
```

```
 @endforeach
```

The Modal

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">TEST</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="review-edit">
                    <div class="review-edit-block">
                        <a href="/reviews/{{ $review->id }}/edit">{{ $review->reviewbody }}</a>

                        <form action="/reviews/{{$review->id}}" method="POST">
                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                          {{ method_field('patch') }}

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea style="position:relative;left:10%;width:375px;"name="reviewbody" class="form-control">{{ $review->reviewbody }}</textarea>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Review</button>



                        </form>
                    </div>


                </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the modal is included after the foreach loop, the variable `$review` will still be set to the value of the last item in the array.

An option is to use Javascript to handle the clicked link, set the specific data into the modal fields and then make the modal visible.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/whuw5p1g/2/)